# Use custom button images with hover and active css styling

Tags: html, css, button

I want to use images I've made for buttons on my site and use the css :hover and :active to change the images. Need them to be submit and also just a basic link to another page.

Comment: Good for you my friend .... where is your try?

Comment: I didn't understand what you actually want.! Add current :hover and :active css snippet so that everyone can understand your idea, code speak more than words. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not understand clearly what you want. But, here goes :-
Using this code, you can achieve the following result:-
The button has a background. When the user hovers over the button, the hovered-background shows up. When the user clicks the button, the page gets redirected to the-page.html

The CSS

```
.button{
   background:url('your_background.png');
}
.button:hover{
   background:url('your-hovered-background.png');
}
```

The HTML

```
<form action="the-page.html">
  <input type="submit" class="button" />
</form>
```

I used input type="submit" as in your question you mentioned that **"need them to be submit"**. If you just want to redirect using a button, and the button need not be submit type, then you can use a `<div>`. Example:-

```
<a href="the-page.html"><div class="button">Redirect</div></a>
```

Comment: Hi, how do i reference a folder in the root directory from the css directory

Comment: Care to explain d downvote